# Mobile detection - Meta tag and max-device-width vs. php user agent?

Tags: iphone, mobile, browser-detection

Which form of mobile detection should I use and why?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)" href="css/mobile.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 319px)" href="css/mobile_simple.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or

```
include('mobile_device_detect.php');
$mobile = mobile_device_detect();
```

Comment: That first example doesn't detect mobile, it just loads different css files based on screen size. If you only have one version of the site and want to style it differently for small screens, that will work fine. If you want to redirect mobile users to another version of your site, you'll need to detect mobile, as in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

You are really looking at a couple different things here...

The html tags are telling the browser how to handle certain situations while the PHP script is detecting a mobile browser while the script is running on the server.

Each has it's own uses... in general, you'll probably end up using a combination of the two.

I usually detect mobile browsers using some server-side script, then output html tags (like the ones you listed) if a mobile browser has been detected.

In other words...
1) user requests a page
2) PHP (or whatever) detects a mobile browser or standard browser
3) if mobile, send the appropriate CSS files, headers, etc. Otherwise, send a different set of CSS files and headers.